# Summernote wysiwyg editor save in codeview not working js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

I'm using [Summernote](http://summernote.org/deep-dive/) as a wysiwyg editor but I have one problem. Most of my text editing goes in the code view and the problem is that if you submit the form while in code view, the edited text does not become saved.

For some reason I need to switch between code view and wysiwyg view to save get the edited text saved. Anyone have any clues on how to fix this?

I have seen this [Not saving content while in code view? #127](https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote/issues/127) but it does not work for me.

Here is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#desc').summernote({
        height: 1000,                 // set editor height
        minHeight: null,             // set minimum height of editor
        maxHeight: null,             // set maximum height of editor
        focus: true,                  // set focus to editable area after initializing summernote
        codemirror: {
          mode: 'text/html',
          htmlMode: true,
          lineNumbers: true,
          theme: 'monokai'
        },
        callbacks: {
          onBlur: function() {
            //should probably do something here
          },
          onInit: function() {
            console.log('Summernote is launched');
            $(this).summernote('codeview.activate');
          }
        }
    });
});
```

If necessary here is the html.

```
<textarea name="desc" id="desc" class="form-control" rows="40"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to do something like this.

```js
$(document).on("submit","#my-form-name",function(e){
    $("#desc").val($('#desc').code());
    return true;
});

$(document).on("submit","#my-form-name",function(e){
    if ($('#desc').summernote('codeview.isActivated')) {
        $('#desc').summernote('codeview.deactivate'); 
    }
});
```

Comment: it does not seem to work for me. The problem is if i try to load anything on a form submit, it return true whatever I do.

Comment: Try to use this.


if ($('#desc').summernote('codeview.isActivated')) {
  $('#desc').summernote('codeview.deactivate');
}

Comment: I've edited the main answer, you can mark it as correct ;)

Comment: After trying many other solutions (like trying to detect class changes with MutationObservers etc), this is the only one that seemed to work.

Answer (score 1):

This copies summernote's code value into the value of the text

```
$(#desc).on('summernote.blur.codeview', function() {
    $(#desc).val($(desc).summernote('code'));
});
```

Looks like using the onblur callback could have also worked: https://summernote.org/deep-dive/#initialization-options

Answer (score 0):

```
   $($('.summernote').closest("form")).on("submit",function(e){
        if ($('.summernote').summernote('codeview.isActivated')) {
            $(".summernote").val($('.summernote').summernote());
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    });

    $($('.summernote').closest("form")).on("submit",function(e){
        if ($('.summernote').summernote('codeview.isActivated')) {
            $('.summernote').summernote('codeview.deactivate'); 
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).